# python, debugging, function is not working

Tags: python, debugging

I need some help to get my function to work:

the function differences should take two codons (strings) and return a list containing 0 if the letter on the position is the same and 1 if it is not, eg. differences('TAG',TAA') should return [0,0,1]

```
def differences(codon1, codon2):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(len(codon1)):
        if codon1[i] != codon2[i]:
            lst.append(1)
        else:
            lst.append(0)
    return lst #Is working, as far as I can see


def differencesToO(codon):#the mistake is somewhere in here!
    L=[]
    O= ['TAG', 'TGA', 'TAA']
    for j in O:
        s=differences(element,codon)
        L.append(sum(s))
    b=min(L)
    return (j,b,s)
```

print differencesToO('TGT') should return ('TGA', 1, [0, 0, 1]),
but is returning ('TAA', 1, [0, 1, 1]).

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to do and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: `h` and `d` are pretty terrible names for functions. Try giving them meaningful names and then perhaps the fact you're calling the wrong one will jump out at you.

Comment: it was a mistake.. But it is still not working.

Comment: you posted code that was incorrect, edited it and introduced new errors (element in defferencesToO is undefined). theres no way of knowing whats the real error you were talking about.

Comment: And now you have vandalized the question by deleting all the code.....

Answer (score 2):

you're calling `s=h(element,codon)` when h is defined to accept only one parameter:
`def h(codon):`